# Dividing a column into three columns

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this table:

```
Name    Address                  Code
James   CT                       Homeaddress
Mark    mark@goole.com           Email
John    John@hotmail.com         homeemail
...
```

This is what I want:

```
Name        Homeaddress      Email           homeemail
james       CT
mark                         mark@google.com
john                                         John@hotmail.com
```

I am creating a view and dont have privilages to alter the base tables. I was thinking maybe an IF statement might help

Comment: ITS KIND OF DIFFERENT AS I DONT HAVE ANY NUMBERS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use CASE expression. Something like that:

```
SELECT Name,
  CASE Code WHEN 'Homeaddress' THEN Address ELSE NULL END AS Homeaddress,
  CASE Code WHEN 'Email' THEN Address ELSE NULL END AS Email,
  CASE Code WHEN 'homeemail' THEN Address ELSE NULL END AS homeemail
FROM yourtable
```